# Identity Server 4 certificate signed by External Certificate Authority

Tags: ssl, salesforce, identityserver4

We are trying to implement OpenId Connect Code flow between Identity Server 4 (provider) and SalesForce (Client) but it seems SalesForce does not like self signed certificate (we get error AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Token&ErrorDescription=invalid_client in salesforce after successfull login in IDP)

Following this thread https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94492/openid-connect-with-custom-idp-authorizationerror-no-oauth-token-empty-respons this could be because our Identity Server certificate is self signed.

How do I create a signing certificate for Identity Server and get is signed by an External Certificate Authority so that it get accepted by SalesForce ?

Comment: Are you sure it's the signing cert we're talking about here and not just the one used for TLS? In OIDC the signing keys can absolutely be self-generated and don't even need an X509 cert at all to work. The protocol relies on TLS to prove the remote machine is what it says it is.

Comment: Hi @Mackie, our TLS certificate (used for HTTPS on identity server) is trusted by Trustwave Organization Validation CA.

Comment: Are you able to provide a little more info about the precise interaction that generates the error?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with the cert.

Comment: hi @identigral would be very appreciated if you could expand on your thoughts

Comment: This particular error message indicates that something in your config on either SF or Identity Server side is very incorrect and this something isn't the cert. Unfortunately it's impossible to pinpoint this something. On SF side, the setup steps are covered in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5. To debug, we recommend you take Identity Server out of the equation for now and send OpenID Connect messages to SF via your favorite command-line or similar HTTP client, then go from there. Alternative debug tool: https://openidconnect.net

Answer (score 0):

So as @identigral posted, this error has nothing to do with certificates.

This is client setup code in identity server that is working for me:

```
new Client {
  ClientId = "SF",
  ClientName = "SalesForce",
  RequireConsent = false,
  AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
  ClientSecrets = {
    new Secret(SalesForceSecretKey.Sha256())
  },
  RequireClientSecret = false,
  AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
  AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
  RedirectUris = {
    SalesForceCallBackURI
  },
  AllowedScopes = {
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile                           
  }
});
```

in `SalesForce`, this is the setup: